# 音楽、音声データをNSData型に変換することは可能でしょうか？

Tags: xcode, objective-c

objective-cで音楽、音声データをNSData型に変換することは可能でしょうか？
可能でしたらそのやり方を教えて欲しいです。

Multiplier Connectivity Frameworkを使って、音楽をNSData型に変換し送信、受信したNSData型の音楽を逆変換して受信するアプリを制作しているのですが、音楽をNSData型に変換する方法がわからず困っています。

Comment: NSData型はバイナリ（バイト列）のデータを入れるものです。 MP3形式の音楽データをバイト列に変換して、それをNSData型に入れるといったことは可能です。　音楽・音声データをどのようにしてバイト列に変換(Coding)するか、あるいは逆変換(Encode)するかは、データの性質と、データを使う用途によって適・不適があります。

Comment: Multiplier Connectivity Frameworkを使って音楽の送受信をしたいと考えていて、画像はNSData型に変換することで送受信できたので音楽も同様にNSData型に変換して送受信をしたいと考えたのですがその方法をがわかりませんでした。